# Virtualbox Guest Additions packages?

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, rpm

As I move to look at virtualbox for the small/medium business where I've used vmware previously, I'm interested in a proper kickstart for my RHEL5/6/7 hosts.

I'm used to using proper vmware guest RPMs I can pre-bake into the (packer) images - and I hope I don't need to list the benefits! - and while I see some RPMs for the actual host machines, I don't see anything for the guests.

Am I overlooking something?  I want to believe that in the larger Oracle organization, who produces VBox and OEL, that the one hand does know what the other one is doing, and they've got the right bits to support their own enterprise products; I just haven't found it yet.  If someone can point me to the installation artifacts they're using in their enterprise organization - preferably something with X stripped out - I'd be ever so grateful.

Thanks!

p.s.:  A dev-ops tag may be best, here, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 4 years old, but I just stumbled upon it today and realized I was in your exact situation a couple years ago.

What we ended up doing was using a Packer definition to automate our image build process.  [Packer supports a `guest_additions_url` option](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html#guest_additions_url).  We pointed this to a local mirror with a copy of the guest additions iso.  Keep in mind, however, that this just uploads the iso to a folder in the VM or inserts it into the virtual CD drive, depending on what other configuration options you've chosen.  Installation is an exercise left to the user - usually a provisioning script will do the trick.  We based our Packer definition on one from [Chef's "Bento" repository](https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/rhel/rhel-7.6-x86_64.json), which uses a [provisioning script to install guest additions](https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/_common/virtualbox.sh) after the iso has been copied into the VM:

```
#!/bin/sh -eux

# set a default HOME_DIR environment variable if not set
HOME_DIR="${HOME_DIR:-/home/vagrant}";

case "$PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE" in
virtualbox-iso|virtualbox-ovf)
    VER="`cat $HOME_DIR/.vbox_version`";
    ISO="VBoxGuestAdditions_$VER.iso";
    mkdir -p /tmp/vbox;
    mount -o loop $HOME_DIR/$ISO /tmp/vbox;
    sh /tmp/vbox/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run \
        || echo "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run exited $? and is suppressed." \
            "For more read https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12479";
    umount /tmp/vbox;
    rm -rf /tmp/vbox;
    rm -f $HOME_DIR/*.iso;
    ;;
esac
```

There are guest additions packages available in repositories for other distros, such as Ubuntu and Arch Linux, but for some reason the closest thing I've found available for RHEL/CentOS are sketchy websites offering up guest additions rpms for ad-hoc downloads, but no actual trustworthy repositories.

P.S.  There is now a [devops-specific Stack Exchange site](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for, but thanks for the response.  Tarballs and installerblobs aren't verifiably consistent at rest, and aren't guaranteed to interface with the software db on the host in terms of requirements.  Comically, Oracle purports to be a purveyor of an RPM-based OS, and is/was a vendor of a PKG-based one before that; and perhaps still hasn't discovered 24-year-old technology for proper artefact creation.  Maybe this year?

Comment: I know "there are no RPMs available for guest additions for EL-based platforms" isn't the answer you _want_ (or the answer I want, for that matter), but it's unfortunately the truth.  The packer-based iso insertion is the next-best option.